# Checking if a variable exists or re-writing the value. Which is quicker?

Tags: php, performance

I have a script that gets ran periodically and I was just curious which way I should code it to maximize speed...

is it quicker to check if a variable's value exists and skip setting it, or simply just set the value again?

e.g., is it faster to:

```
if($variable=="") { $variable = "blah"; }
```

OR just have

```
$variable = "blah";
```

OR is this a non-issue? will the speed differences at the end of the day be negligible?

thanks for your help...

Comment: If the variable's value is constant, it's not exactly a variable, is it?

Comment: If that gains you more speed, I wonder how perfectly optimized your script is already ... ^^ http://i.stack.imgur.com/DJcPs.jpg

Comment: well, you're right I don't know much PHP compared to many people, i'm sure.  just trying to learn the correct way to do things as I go..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the speed difference is negligible, but the logic of your two examples is fundamentally different (setting a value unconditionally, versus setting a value only if the current value is empty).

Answer (score 0):

Set the variable again, otherwise php has to check